# Android RecyclerView's EditText swaps its position after entering data and scroll down

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` which consists of a `TextView` and `EditText`, for the `TextView` the `RecyclerView` working perfectly fine with me, but for the `EditText`, if I enter value in first cell and keep on entering for other cell and scroll the entered value above will be not present.

```
public class Assesment_MarkcardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Assesment_MarkcardAdapter.ContactViewHolder> {

    private String[] mDataset;

    public Assesment_MarkcardAdapter(String[] myDataset)
    {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    private List<Assesment_cardinfo> contactList;
    private static String LOG_TAG = "Assesment_MarkcardAdapter";


    public Assesment_MarkcardAdapter(List<Assesment_cardinfo> contactList) {
        this.contactList = contactList;
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contactList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ContactViewHolder contactViewHolder, int i)
    {

        mDataset = new String[contactList.size()];
        Assesment_cardinfo ci = contactList.get(i);
        contactViewHolder.studentname.setText(ci.getStudentname());
        contactViewHolder.studentid.setText(ci.getStudentid());
        contactViewHolder.grade.setText(ci.getGrade());
        contactViewHolder.improvement.setText(ci.getImprovements());
        contactViewHolder.grade.setTag(ci);
        contactViewHolder.improvement.setTag(ci);
        contactViewHolder.myCustomEditTextListener.updatePosition(i);
        contactViewHolder.myCustomEditTextListener2.updatePosition2(i);
        //contactViewHolder.grade.setText(mDataset[i]);
    }

    @Override
    public Assesment_MarkcardAdapter.ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)
    {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.assesment_markcard, viewGroup, false);

        return new ContactViewHolder(itemView , new MyCustomEditTextListener(),new MyCustomEditTextListener2());
    }

    public static class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public MyCustomEditTextListener myCustomEditTextListener;
        public MyCustomEditTextListener2 myCustomEditTextListener2;

        protected TextView studentname;
        protected TextView studentid;
        protected EditText grade;
        protected EditText improvement;


        public ContactViewHolder(View v, MyCustomEditTextListener myCustomEditTextListener, MyCustomEditTextListener2 myCustomEditTextListener2 ) {
            super(v);
            studentname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_student_name);
            studentid = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_student_id);
            grade = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edtxt_grade);
            this.myCustomEditTextListener = myCustomEditTextListener;
            grade.addTextChangedListener(myCustomEditTextListener);
            improvement = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edtxt_improvement);
            this.myCustomEditTextListener2 = myCustomEditTextListener2;
            improvement.addTextChangedListener(myCustomEditTextListener2);

        }

    }
    private class MyCustomEditTextListener implements TextWatcher
    {
        private int position;

        public void updatePosition(int position)
        {
            this.position = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3)
        {
            // no op
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3)
        {
            contactList.get(position).setGrade(charSequence.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            // no op
        }
    }

    private class MyCustomEditTextListener2 implements TextWatcher
    {
        private int position;

        public void updatePosition2(int position)
        {
            this.position = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3)
        {
            // no op
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3)
        {
            contactList.get(position).setImprovements(charSequence.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            // no op
        }
    }
    public List<Assesment_cardinfo> getStudentLists()
    {
        return contactList;
    }
}
```

Comment: In `onTextChanged()` write `contactList.get(position).setGrade(charSequence.toString())` insted of `Assesment_cardinfo ci = contactList.get(position);
            ci.setGrade(charSequence.toString());`, and try once

Comment: No.. still the same @NigamPatro

Comment: Please try with the posted answer.

Comment: yes i did.. nothing changed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these two lines, inside your `onBindViewHolder()`

```
contactViewHolder.grade.setText(ci.getGrade());
contactViewHolder.improvement.setText(ci.getImprovement());
```

after setting the listeners, that means after

```
contactViewHolder.myCustomEditTextListener.updatePosition(i);
contactViewHolder.myCustomEditTextListener2.updatePosition2(i);
```

these two lines of code.

this will work for sure.This happens because you are not setting text to the EditText and after recycle, the text is already gone. So, try this, it will definitly work.

Comment: yes now the text s not repeating if i scroll .but when i scroll up the entered will not be there

Comment: OK. give me some time.

Comment: sure.. i dont have reputations yet.. once i earn that.. first i'll

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem.

```
holder.editQty.addTextChangedListener
```

When you're adding a Textwatcher to Edittext that was added to array of listeners so this is bad practice.

Either you have to remove all old listener with set null.

```
 holder.editQty.addTextChangedListener(null);
 holder.editQty.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher())
```

It will resolve the problem.

Comment: This solution works for me. I added EditText text change listener in viewholder and that listener cause the problem when views are recycle.

Comment: This uses array list, so by adding null you are just creating another entry for listener with null, the old listener is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Its really bad to put input fields in recycler view. Try restructring your UI design. Recycler view should always have read only fields. Even then you want to achieve this try creating views dynamically and adding it to the rooot layout. 
For instance Have a XML file where linear layout would be your root. Create one more XML file and keep adding this template to your root view.

**Probably Something like this**
this will be your root layout instear od recycler view

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

//Create a template layout.You need to add the property i am just skippint it
<LinearLayout>
<TextView/>
<EditText/>


// In you activity write a method to create a view dynamically from template and add it to your root Layout. 

LinearLayout rootLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);

createChilds(rootLayout);

private void createChilds(LinearLayout rootLayout)
{
LinearLayout  childContainer=(LinearLayout)LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.template_layout,null);
TextView tv=childContainer.findViewById(R.id.textviewid);
EditText et=childContainer.findViewById(R.id.edittextviewid);

// you can register for textwatcher for edit text if you want

//Add it to roolayout
rootLayout.addView(childContainer);
}
```

Comment: But how will i initialize the other xml in same adapter class

Comment: Do Not use recycler view. Replace it with LinearLayout as root element. Give soime ID. Have a method to create a template layout and keep adding it to your root layout.